# How do I convert an array of Characters into binary?

Tags: binary, char, bit

I have created a string and converted it to an array of characters. I now need to convert that array of characters into binary. How do I go about doing this??
This is what I have:

```
 String word = "Hello";
 char[] w = word.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Possible lookup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863499/conversion-of-char-to-binary-in-c

Comment: Do the same, except that you will have to iterate the same operation for each character