# How do I print the binary of characters from an input file?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I need to be able to take a textfile:
e.g. text.txt

```
a
b
c
0
1
2
```

and I need to print the binary values of these characters. This is what I have written so far:

```
#include "p01.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  char buf[50];

  for(long i =0; i<6; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%c", &buf[i]);
    fgets(buf, 50, fptr);
    fprintf(stdout,"[%d]%c %d\n", i, buf[i], (int)buf[i]);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the current output I have:

```
[0]
 10
[1] 0
[2]c 99
[3]0 48
[4]1 49
[5]2 50
```

I am not really sure why it is printing a newline, skipping a and b, and then I am not even sure how to approach printing their bits. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "binary"? As in `00101001`? Hint: [There are answers like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384262/convert-string-to-binary-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is:

```c
for (long i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%c", &buf[i]);
    fgets(buf, 50, fptr);
    fprintf(stdout, "[%d]%c %d\n", i, buf[i], (int)buf[i]);
}
```

On the iteration when `i` is `0`, you read `a` into `buf[0]` with `scanf()`.  Then, the `fgets()` call reads the newline over `buf[0]` and places a null byte to mark the end of the input over `buf[1]`.  Therefore, the `fprintf(stdout, …)` call (conventionally written `printf(…)`) produces the data for a newline as that's the character stored in `buf[0]`.

On the iteration when `i` is `1`, you read `b` into `buf[1]` with `scanf()`.  Then the call to `fgets()` reads the newline over `buf[0]` and places a null byte to mark the end of the input over `buf[1]`.  Therefore, the printing operation prints the data about the null byte as that's the character stored in `buf[1]`.

On the subsequent iterations, the `fgets()` call continues to write over `buf[0]` and `buf[1]`, but the rest of your code is looking after those characters and isn't affected.

Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` like this is dubious.  It would probably be best to use just

```
if (scanf(fptr, " %c", &buf[i]) != 1)
    break;
```

and drop the `fgets()` completely.  The leading space in the format string skips optional white space, meaning blanks, tabs and (crucially) newlines.  On the first iteration, it skips nothing; on the second, it skips the newline and proceeds to read `b`.  And there's no confusing overwriting going on.  If you add a null terminator, you'd have the string `abc123` in `buf` after the loop and null termination.

Alternatively, just use `fgets()` and always work with `buf[0]`.

Note that the cast to `int` is immaterial.  When a `char` value is passed to `printf()` or `fprintf()`, it is automatically converted to `int` — both the arguments `buf[i]` are passed as `int`, regardless of the presence or absence of a cast.  See C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7) — and ¶6 is also relevant for the definition of *default argument promotions*.  There's room for more discussion, but it is more complex than needed to answer this question.